# Tour a $M\times N$ chess board with a piece that moves in each turn along the diagonal of a $m\times n$ rectangle

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chessboard

Here a "tour" is a sequence of moves that visit each square of the board. A square can be visited more than once if necessary.

For example, in a $8\times 8$ chess board, a knight which makes $2\times1$ type moves can tour the whole board from an arbitrary starting point, but a bishop which makes $1\times 1$ (or $k\times k$) type moves can not. What condition must $M,N,m,n$ satisfy so that a full board tour from **any** starting point is possible?

Comment: I assume that the piece which moves "along" the diagonals of a rectangle jumps from corner to corner without "visiting" the squares in between ? The standard name for that piece is [$(m,n)$-leaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece#Leapers). "Tour" is the standard name for a sequence of moves that visits each square **exactly once**, as in the classic problem of the [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour). What (I think) you are asking, in plain language: On which rectangular chessboards can an $(m,n)$-leaper get from any square to any other square?

Comment: Since you allow squares to be visited repeatedly, there is no need to say "from any starting point"; if you can do it from one starting point, you can do it from any starting point.

Comment: You may as well assune that $m,n$ are relatively prime, and not both odd; otherwise your "tour" wil be impossible no matter how big $M$ and $N$ are.

Comment: @bof Not in every case. A bishop, for example can reach every light square from every other light square, but not from a dark square.

Comment: @Peter What does that have to do with my comment that, if you can "tour the whole board" from one starting point, you can do it frim any starting point? A bishop cannot tour the whole board, no matter where it starts.

Comment: @bof In the second comment, it is not clear that you still mean the case that a tour is possible (in which case the comment is obviously true). I only wanted to point out that in general, this need not to be true, not only with the bishops that cannot reach every square anyway.

Comment: @Peter I was obviously commenting on the OP's statement "that a full board tour from **any** starting point is possible", and pointing out that, with his peculiar definition of "tour", he could have left out "from **any** starting point".